# Defining a predicate that depends on a condition

Tags: inheritance, prolog

I need to define a predicate eats/3 (Eater, Food, Time) which checks whether the Eater will eat the Food, depending on what Time it is.

I have the following semantic framework describing the biological relations between its components:

```
is_a(animal, living_being).
is_a(plant, living_being).
is_a(herbivore, animal).
is_a(carnivore, animal).
is_a(omnivore, animal).
is_a(flowering_plant, plant).
is_a(nonflowering_plant, plant).
is_a(fox, carnivore).
is_a(cow, herbivore).
is_a(hen, omnivore).
is_a(bessie, cow).
is_a(hawke, fox).
is_a(coco, hen).
is_a(cabbage, nonflowering_plant).
is_a(rose, flowering_plant).
```

I also have the eats/2 predicate:

```
eats(carnivore, animal).
eats(herbivore, plant).
eats(omnivore, animal).
eats(omnivore, plant).
```

There are predicates animal_food/1 and plant_food/1:

```
animal_food(animal).
plant_food(plant).
```

The condition is that animal_food will only be eaten between the Time-s 22:00-06.00 and plant_food will only be eaten between the Time-s 06:01-21:59.

For example:

```
?- eats(fox, hen, 02.00).
```

will return true if fox is a carnivore or omnivore, hen is animal_food and carnivores/omnivores eat at night based on animal_food being eaten at night.

Another example:

```
?- eats(bessie, cabbage, 14.00).
```

will return true if bessie is a herbivore, cabbage is plant_food and herbivores eat during the day based on plant_food being eaten during the day.

Also, the eater cannot be of the same class as the Food (for example, foxes cannot eat foxes).

What I have made so far is this:

```
subclass(Who,Whose):-
    is_a(Who,Whose).
subclass(Who,Whose):-
    is_a(Who,Intermediary),
    subclass(Intermediary,Whose).
```

This predicate subclass/2 will check whether or not it will eventually find a relation between the two classes.

With this I made a predicate eats/2:

```
eats(Who,Whom):-subclass(Who, Eater), subclass(Whom,Food), eats(Eater,Food), Who \= Food.
```

I have also made a predicate animal_food/1 and plant_food/1 so I could check if, for example a hen was of the type animal_food and a cabbage was of the type plant_food:

```
animal_food(Who):-subclass(Who,Whose), animal_food(Whose), Who \= Whose.
plant_food(Who):-subclass(Who,Whose), plant_food(Whose), Who \= Whose.
```

With all this I can for example get true if I ask

```
eats(fox,hen)
```

or

```
eats(cow,cabbage)
```

but where I am having an issue is 
1)  the Time condition of eats/3.

I have sort of an idea in pseudocode for checking the Time condition:

```
21.59 -> 21*60 + 59 = 1298. (minutes)  
06.01 -> 6*60 + 1 = 361. (minutes)  
(Time >= 361, Time=< 1298) -> daytime  
Otherwise -> nighttime
```

but I am not quite sure how to parse something like 15.30 so that I can make the check. Make it a list and then do the multiplication on the numbers separately?

and

2)  constructing the predicate so that it would check all the conditions (Eater being carnivore/omnivore/herbivore, Food being plant_food or animal_food and Time fitting with Food).
I have made the simple checks that check for empty variables

```
eats([],Food,Time):- fail.
eats(Eater,[],Time):- fail.
eats(Eater,Food,[]):- fail.
```

I assume the main check would be, for example, for a fox:

```
% this is pseudocode  
eats(fox,hen,05.59):- Term1 =.. [subclass,fox,X], Term1, (animal_food(hen);plant_food(hen)), Number is 5*60 + 59, (Number>= 361, Number=< 1298) % if the Food is plant food; (!(Number>= 361, Number=< 1298)) %if the Food is animal_food
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > but I am not quite sure how to parse something like 15.30 so that I can make the check. Make it a list and then do the multiplication on the numbers separately?

Let's review your condition:

> The condition is that animal_food will only be eaten between the Time-s 22:00-06.00 and plant_food will only be eaten between the Time-s 06:01-21:59.

I probably wouldn't encode time as a decimal number, but let's say you did; I think the predicate would work fine if you expressed it in the natural way:

```
daytime(Num) :- 6.01 =< Num, Num =< 21.59.
nighttime(Num) :- (22 =< Num, Num =< 24); (0 =< Num, Num =< 6).
```

This works; the problem is that it also works for crazy times (6.79) and doing arithmetic on time in this representation is not going to work properly. But, to be honest, every representation has shortcomings and this one is actually probably sufficient for your problem as described, so I would probably tolerate it. But I'm pretty tolerant.

In Prolog, you get the benefit that you can use standard operators or define new operators if it suits your problem. Colons tend to be problematic, but it seemed to work for me to do something like this:

```
daytime(Time) :- 6:01 @=< Time, Time @=< 21:59.
nighttime(Time) :- (22:00 @=< Time, Time @=< 24:00) ; (0 @=< Time, Time @=< 6:00).
```

The atom comparison there continues to allow for invalid times, but there's no particular reason to address it in the problem description you gave.

2. > constructing the predicate so that it would check all the conditions (Eater being carnivore/omnivore/herbivore, Food being plant_food or animal_food and Time fitting with Food).

I would remove your fail cases; Prolog usually doesn't need any help figuring out that things fail when they are incomplete. You can instead just use things assuming they are there and if they aren't, it will fail.

You have a natural language definition of what you want it to do, so start there:

```
eats(Eater, Food, Time) :-
    eats(Eater, Food),
    animal_food(Food),
    nighttime(Time).
eats(Eater, Food, Time) :-
    eats(Eater, Food),
    plant_food(Food),
    daytime(Time).
```

I think you actually have all the other parts you need. Does this work?

3. **Edit**: Valid time

As far as I can see, your task doesn't actually rely on any arithmetic or conversions with time. So all we have to do to worry about valid time is test for it, and make sure that test is in play.

```
valid(HH:MM) :- between(0, 24, HH), between(0, 60, MM).
```

This predicate affirms the validity of a time value. If an invalid time value is passed in, it will fail. Try it. Now let's plug it into our other time predicates:

```
daytime(Time) :- 
    valid(Time), 6:01 @=< Time, Time @=< 21:59.
nighttime(Time) :- 
    valid(Time), 
    ((22:00 @=< Time, Time @=< 24:00) ; 
     (0 @=< Time, Time @=< 6:00)).
```

That should be the only change you need to make.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, your solution works for the examples but I think the task does require that the hours and minutes in Time do not go over 23 and 59, respectively.  How would I go ahead and do that?

Comment: @T44v1 take a look at what I've added on to address that. Helps?

Comment: One last thing is that the format for Time is HH.MM not HH:MM. Would simply replacing the ":"-s with "."-s help or is there something incorrect here?

Comment: @T44v1 If you do that, you're making floating point numbers and you can't pattern match the pieces apart. But you could do the same kind of thing I'm doing, by doing some arithmetic to get the fractional part and the integral part.

Comment: Well, I basically managed to get it to work with "."-s, but the issue seems to be that if I for example try to ask eats(fox,chicken,03.59) I actually can potentially get more than one true as a result if I use ; on the result. I think the issue is that I should only be getting it once. Maybe one of my conditions is too lenient?

Comment: There are three clauses in the body of `eats/3`; try each one of them in turn with the same instantiation and see if you can find the one that is producing spurious results. I would wager it's `animal_food(Food)` or `plant_food(Food)` and the cause is probably the subclass search. But you can look for yourself, maybe use `trace/0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156863/discussion-between-t44v1-and-daniel-lyons).

Answer (score 1):

Right, many thanks to @daniel-lyons for the help. I had some conflicts regarding the names of the predicates with the facts. I ended up replacing eats/2 with eats_rule/2 and plant_food/1 plus animal_food/1 with plant_food_rule/1 plus animal_food_rule/1. The only thing I changed was the name of the predicates.

The answer:

```
eats(Who,Whom):-subclass(Who, Eater), subclass(Whom,Food), eats(Eater,Food), Who \= Food.
time_to_minutes(TimeAsNumber, TimeAsMinutes):-
    Hours is floor(TimeAsNumber),
    Minutes is integer(100*(TimeAsNumber-Hours)),
    between(0,23,Hours), between(0,59,Minutes), 
    TimeAsMinutes is ((Hours *60) + Minutes).
daytime(Time):- time_to_minutes(Time,TimeResult), (TimeResult>=361, TimeResult=< 1319) .
nighttime(Time) :- time_to_minutes(Time,TimeResult), ((TimeResult>= 1320 , TimeResult=< 1439) ; 
     (TimeResult>= 0, TimeResult=< 360)).
eats(Who,Whom,Time):- eats_rule(Who,Whom), animal_food_rule(Whom), nighttime(Time).
eats(Who,Whom,Time):- eats_rule(Who,Whom), plant_food_rule(Whom), daytime(Time).
```